# Getting Data In AngularJs From WebSql

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, angularjs, jaydata, angularjs-factory

I am developing android app using `AngularJs`, `JQuery Mobile` with `JQM-AngularJS Adapter` and for server side i use `JayData`to generate `DataBase` and then dumb data in `WebSql`.
Now i want to get data from `webSql` to my `DropDowns` on runtime but it could not initialize in `DropDowns` Here is mu code that i produced

**DropDown Code**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" ng-controller="foodSelection">
    <li><span>Catagory</span>
        <select id="selectCatagoryFood" data-role="listview" data-native-menu="true"
            ng-init="foodCatagory = foodCatagories.cast[0]"
            ng-options="foodCatagory as foodCatagory.text for foodCatagory in foodCatagories.cast"
            ng-model="foodCatagory"
            ng-change="changeFoodCatagory()">
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Angular and JayData Code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('foodCatagories',function(){
     var foodCatagories = {};
     foodCatagories.cast = [
     {
         value: "000",
         text: "Select Any"
    }
    ];
return foodCatagories;
});
myApp.controller('foodSelection',function($scope,foodCatagories){
$scope.foodCatagories = foodCatagories; // First Add Dummy Data
_context.onReady(
{
    success:function()
            {   //Context For Getting Data -- JayData Method --
                _context.FoodGroup.forEach(function(FG)
                {
                    //Get Data From WebSql
                        console.log(FG.FoodGroupID);
                        console.log(FG.Description);

                }).then(function()
                {
                 // Now Here I want To Dumped in to dropdown
                });
            },
    error: function (error)
           {
               alert(error);
               console.log(error);
               alert("error");
           }
}).then(function(){

});
$scope.changeFoodCatagory = function(){
    alert($scope.foodCatagory.value);
}
});
```

I need data on runtime so what should i do for it?

Comment: JQM: when adding options to select dynamically, call `.selectmenu('refresh')`.

Comment: Remove `data-role=listview` attribute from the `select`, you can't combine both.

Comment: @Omar this is not a case here its use Data Binding using AngularJS like this example http://jsfiddle.net/rcjWu/ there. I want to add data where i asked in question but when i did, it didn't add and not any error on console

Comment: it works all fine with the attributes that i added now i want to bind new data when i get data from server

Comment: Ok, just some JQM tips for free. Good luck :)